# Flutter WooCommerce Customer registeration failed using Dio?

Tags: wordpress, flutter, woocommerce-rest-api

I am buidling flutter woocommerce store app for customers. I want to create/register a new customer using `Dio()` and I am using WordPress Plugin `JWT Authentication for WP REST API` for authentication. Here if i want to access  URL for Customers Its showing following response. URL= "`https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/customers`"

```
{
code: "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view",
message: "Sorry, you cannot list resources.",
data: {
status: 401
}
}
```

My Custutomer Model file is:

```
class CustomerModel {
  String email;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String password;
  CustomerModel(
      {required this.email,
      required this.firstName,
      required this.lastName,
      required this.password});
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = {};
    map.addAll({
      'email': email,
      'first_name': firstName,
      'last_name': lastName,
      'password': password,
      'username': email
    });
    return map;
  }
}
```

My API Service Mothod to create customer is:

```
Future<bool> createCustomer(CustomerModel model) async {
    var authToken =
        base64.encode(utf8.encode(Config.key + ':' + Config.sceret));
    print(authToken);
    bool ret = false;
    try {
      print("${Config.url+ Config.customerURL}");
      var response = await Dio().post(Config.url + Config.customerURL,
          data: model.toJson(),
          options: new Options(headers: {
            HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Basic $authToken',
            HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json'
          }));

      print(response.statusCode);
      if (response.statusCode == 201) {
        ret = true;
      }
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      if (e.response?.statusCode == 404) {
        ret = false;
      } else {
        ret = false;
      }
    }
    return ret;
  }
```

My model Perameter Data is in following format:

```
{
 email: qas@gmail.com,
 first_name: qasim,
 last_name: ali,
 password: qasim123,
 username: qas@gmail.com
}
```

My `createCustomer` Method is always returning false ::: I mean `Dio().Post()` is not working successfully kindly guide

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Basic`,

```
HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Basic $authToken',
```

Use `Bearer` in the header.

```
HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $authToken',
```

Comment: I tried it but not working .... it seems that its woocommerce side error that is not allowing us to read/write on tables

Comment: No, it is not. Error 401 is a token expiration error, are you familiar with token refresh?

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue and manage to resolve it by removing authorazation header and append the key and secret to the post path,I am just not sure if this is the safe way to implement it.  see the code below

```
var response = await Dio().post(Config.url + Config.customerURL + '?consumer_key=' + Config.key + '&consumer_secret=' + Config.secret,
    data:model.toJson(),

    options: Options(headers: {
      //HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader:'Bearer: $authToken',
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
    },
```

I added back the authorazation header and its working too.